# js drag and drop только по строке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить рабочий скрипт по моим требованиям. Необходимо, что бы перетаскиваемые элементы можно было менять только в одном блоки по строке. А у меня сейчас получается, что любой элемент можно менять как и по строке так и по столбцу.
То есть запретить перетаскивание элементов по блокам

```js
// Full example
(function() {
    var id_ = 'columns-full';
    var cols_ = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id_ + ' .column');
    var dragSrcEl_ = null;

    this.handleDragStart = function(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

        dragSrcEl_ = this;

        // this/e.target is the source node.
        this.classList.add('moving');
    };

    this.handleDragOver = function(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
        }

        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

        return false;
    };

    this.handleDragEnter = function(e) {
        this.classList.add('over');
    };

    this.handleDragLeave = function(e) {
        // this/e.target is previous target element.
        this.classList.remove('over');
    };

    this.handleDrop = function(e) {
        // this/e.target is current target element.

        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
        }

        // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same column we're dragging.
        if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
            dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');

            // Set number of times the column has been moved.
            var count = this.querySelector('.count');
            var newCount = parseInt(count.getAttribute('data-col-moves')) + 1;
            count.setAttribute('data-col-moves', newCount);
            count.textContent = 'moves: ' + newCount;
        }

        return false;
    };

    this.handleDragEnd = function(e) {
        // this/e.target is the source node.
        [].forEach.call(cols_, function(col) {
            col.classList.remove('over');
            col.classList.remove('moving');
        });
    };

    [].forEach.call(cols_, function(col) {
        col.setAttribute('draggable', 'true'); // Enable columns to be draggable.
        col.addEventListener('dragstart', this.handleDragStart, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handleDragEnter, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleDragLeave, false);
        col.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
    });
})();
```

```css
.column {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #666666;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
    cursor: move;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}

.column header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    text-shadow: #000 0 1px;
}

.column {
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.column.over {
    border: 2px dashed #000;
}

.column.moving {
    opacity: 0.25;
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

.column .count {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-shadow: #fff 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="columns-full" class="columns clearfix">
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>D</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
    </div>


    <div id="columns-full" class="columns clearfix">
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>D</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
    </div>



    <div id="columns-full" class="columns clearfix">
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
        <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>D</header><div class="count" data-col-moves="0"></div></div>
    </div>
```

Спасибо